# Blood Type Probability

Tags: probability

I'm given this table:

[image: blood_type_contingency_table]

I have to work out the numbers. I have only been able to pin down the easiest I guess.

I have $$P(A)=0,70$$ so $$P(\neg A)=0,30$$
the same way I have $$P(B)=0,50$$
thus $$P(\neg B)=0,50$$
as well. What I cannot get are the other numbers on the table, as I don't know how to since blood types aren't mutually exclusive or have the same probability (you can either have A, or B, or both, or none).

Can you please help me on how to figure out the rest of the table?

Okay, since there were missing elements, apparently these are the results I'm supposed to get, I just don't know how and none of the answers seemed to satisfy the results:

[image: Solved Blood Type Contingency Table]

I also have this specific formula since the probabilities are non-exclusive and non-equiprobabilistic:
$$P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B)$$

Comment: I think you are right that there is not enough information to figure out the missing probabilities. Knowing the row and column sums does not determine the entries. One more datum would do the job.

Comment: Are we supposed to assume independence?

Comment: I don't know if editing the original post will notify you, but I've added more data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show you that this exercise has **no unique solution** provided that the table is a classic **2-way-contingency table** without assuming the probabilities to be independent. At the end you see the solution for the case of independence.

Given the data the entries must satisfy the following:
$$\begin{matrix}
x & \color{blue}{0.7}-x & \color{blue}{0.7} \\
y & \color{green}{0.3}-y & \color{green}{0.3} = 1-\color{blue}{0.7} \\
x+y=\color{orange}{0.5} & \color{orange}{0.5} & 1
 \end{matrix}$$
So, 
$$\mbox{for any }0 \leq y\leq 0.3 \mbox{ set } x=0.5-y$$
you get a possible set of **valid table entries**.

For example
$$\color{red}{y=0.2} \mbox{ and } \color{red}{x= 0.3} \mbox{ or } y=0.1 \mbox{ and } x= 0.4$$

**Conclusion:**

So, you need more information. This could be, for example, the **independence** of the probablities in question.

Then, you would get:

$$\begin{matrix}
\color{orange}{0.5}\cdot\color{blue}{0.7} = 0.35 & 0.35 & \color{blue}{0.7} \\
\color{orange}{0.5}\cdot \color{green}{0.3} = 0.15 & 0.15 & \color{green}{0.3} \\
\color{orange}{0.5} & \color{orange}{0.5} & 1
 \end{matrix}$$
**Update:** (after OP edited post)

Your specific solution corresponds to one of the examples I gave (highlighted now in $\color{red}{red}$).

**Important** is to understand the first part of my answer:
**Without any further information** there are **infinitely many solutions** to your problem.

Comment: I edited the post to show the solution, I don't know how to get to it, but you look like you were on a good path. I don't know if editing the original post notifies the people that have already answered, so can you please check it out?

Comment: Your comment under my solution gives me a notification. So, I am seeing it right now.

Comment: I added an update to my answer. Fact is, if you got only the information you provided in your post, you did not have a chance to calculate the solution you added to the post.

Comment: Would it be possible with a system of 4 equations with 4 unknowns? EDIT: Okay, no, I can't. Teacher fixed his mistake and said we would be given the probability of one of the cases in the table. Sorry for wasting time.

Comment: You are welcome. Never trust teachers nor textbooks too much.  :-D

Answer (score 0):

The table just corresponds to a Venn diagram.

[image: Venn_dia_1]

Since there is nothing else than $A$ and $B$ (and their complements), then just calculate the areas of the various combinations.